# Topic based subscribe and publish with EasyNetQ

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, easynetq, rabbitmqctl

We have 2 .nwt windows services running and I am currently trying to implement a system where if System 1 is down due to any error, System 2 also has to be brought down. We are making use of RabbitMQ for the same. When SYstem 1 is down, it will publish a message to a queue and System 2 should take message from this queue.
So in short my requirement is,
System1 subscribes to Queue1 with topic - System1, but it publishes to Queue2 - with topic System2, similarly
System 2 subscribes to Queue2 with topic - System 2 and publishes to Queue1 with topic System1.
Is there any way to achieve this rather than hardcoding the values - System1 and System2 as the topics.

Answer (score 0):

Went ahead with using hardcoded values of topics.